# После переноса перестали работать компоненты Yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. При переносе файлов Yii2 Advanced с одного домена на другой возникли проблемы: приложение не видит установленные мною компоненты. К примеру:

```
Class lajax\languagepicker\Component does not exist
```

Но на самом деле и сам класс существует, и все файлы в порядке. Пробовал несколько раз заменять файлы - ни в какую. Пробовал поставить чистый Yii2 с заменой vendor и добавление своих моделей, контроллеров и вида - аналогичная проблема.

В чём может быть проблема?

UPD: Все стандартные функции работают, проблема лишь с компонентами, которые подключил во время работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой. При полном копировании сайта vendor почему-то не переносятся установленные дополнения. Для этого через Composer нужно провести update зависимостей.

Команда:

```
php composer.phar update
```